# Android Studio 2.1 Gradle sync error after implemented AAR library

Tags: java, android, aar, android-studio-2.1, android-multidex

I have added AAR Library file into Project. After successfully added, After implementing the aar library into my main code, while gradle sync , am getting these exception..

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
Error:1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Return code 1 for dex process
```

I have tried Build Clean, Rebuild, Restart to Studio, many times Gradle sync,and Multidex also enabled true
getting the above mentioned error.

anyone help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I cleared the problem.

I have Followed this Steps in Android Studio 2.1:
File-Settings-Build,Execution,Deployment
select - Instant Run - UnCheck the First Option
"Enable Instant Run to hot swap code/resource changes on deploy(default enabled)"

then, finally, Clean and Rebuild and Run the Project.